# IE10, Same Domain IFRAME and Style shset

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-10

In my application, I am including one page within another via an iframe. I'm working on a quick prototype here, so I don't want to take additional time right now to implement something fancier].

Everything looks good except for IE10 on Windows 7. From what I can tell, the style sheet of the iframe is being added into the cascade of the style sheet for the page and causing strange display errors. I'm a little dumbfounded this is even possible.

If I comment out the iframe, everything renders correctly.

I can also see the styles changing as the iframe loads:

Pre-iframe: http://screencast.com/t/8qcl2U4Uuy

Post-iframe: http://screencast.com/t/fzR9esWsq

Anyone else experience strange behavior like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share with us a very basic example via code? Something we can run locally and test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. My coworker was actually able to help me trace this back to an issue with the IE10 developer toolbar.

I was able to create a file that replicates the issue: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1686497/iframe.zip

If you open the index, you'll notice that there is no margin on the body. While you have that page open and you open the F12 Developer Toolbar in IE10 (10.0.9200.16540) on Windows 7 (at least), you will see the body becomes padded and the parent window font switches to Times. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: How odd - thanks for answering your question as I've had just the same issue